# How to bypass google's cookie consent redirect when making a request with Guzzle

Tags: symfony, drupal, guzzle

I am using Guzzle to pull data from content that the end location of a google rss feed link. e.g.

https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiVWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmxvbmRvbi1maXJlLmdvdi51ay9pbmNpZGVudHMvMjAyMy9qYW51YXJ5L21haXNvbmV0dGUtZmlyZS1zdHJlYXRoYW0taGlsbC_SAQA?oc=5

When using curl with -L (location) flag it appears to bypass the consent redirect and pulls   through the end location content.

I am using Drupal 10 with httpclient available which I understand uses Guzzle 7.  How do I do the same there?

When enabling 'track redirects' guzzle feature I can see it appears to be getting stuck redirecting to google consent page and not redirecting to the end location?

e.g.

`An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: /batch?id=328&op=do_nojs&op=do StatusText: parsererror ResponseText: Redirecting https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiTmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm15bG9uZG9uLm5ld3MvbmV3cy9wcm9wZXJ0eS9pbS1lc3RhdGUtYWdlbnQtcmVudGluZy1zb3V0aC0yNjA2MDI1ONIBUmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm15bG9uZG9uLm5ld3MvbmV3cy9wcm9wZXJ0eS9pbS1lc3RhdGUtYWdlbnQtcmVudGluZy1zb3V0aC0yNjA2MDI1OC5hbXA?oc=5 to https://consent.google.com/m?continue=https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiTmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm15bG9uZG9uLm5ld3MvbmV3cy9wcm9wZXJ0eS9pbS1lc3RhdGUtYWdlbnQtcmVudGluZy1zb3V0aC0yNjA2MDI1ONIBUmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm15bG9uZG9uLm5ld3MvbmV3cy9wcm9wZXJ0eS9pbS1lc3RhdGUtYWdlbnQtcmVudGluZy1zb3V0aC0yNjA2MDI1OC5hbXA?oc%3D5&gl=GB&m=0&pc=n&hl=en-US&src=1 Redirecting https://consent.google.com/m?continue=https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiTmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm15bG9uZG9uLm5ld3MvbmV3cy9wcm9wZXJ0eS9pbS1lc3RhdGUtYWdlbnQtcmVudGluZy1zb3V0aC0yNjA2MDI1ONIBUmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm15bG9uZG9uLm5ld3MvbmV3cy9wcm9wZXJ0eS9pbS1lc3RhdGUtYWdlbnQtcmVudGluZy1zb3V0aC0yNjA2MDI1OC5hbXA?oc%3D5&gl=GB&m=0&pc=n&hl=en-US&src=1 to https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiTmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm15bG9uZG9uLm5ld3MvbmV3cy9wcm9wZXJ0eS9pbS1lc3RhdGUtYWdlbnQtcmVudGluZy1zb3V0aC0yNjA2MDI1ONIBUmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm15bG9uZG9uLm5ld3MvbmV3cy9wcm9wZXJ0eS9pbS1lc3RhdGUtYWdlbnQtcmVudGluZy1zb3V0aC0yNjA2MDI1OC5hbXA?oc=5&ucbcb=1 Redirecting https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiTmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm15bG9uZG9uLm5ld3MvbmV3cy9wcm9wZXJ0eS9pbS1lc3RhdGUtYWdlbnQtcmVudGluZy1zb3V0aC0yNjA2MDI1ONIBUmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm15bG9uZG9uLm5ld3MvbmV3cy9wcm9wZXJ0eS9pbS1lc3RhdGUtYWdlbnQtcmVudGluZy1zb3V0aC0yNjA2MDI1OC5hbXA?oc=5&ucbcb=1 to https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiTmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm15bG9uZG9uLm5ld3MvbmV3cy9wcm9wZXJ0eS9pbS1lc3RhdGUtYWdlbnQtcmVudGluZy1zb3V0aC0yNjA2MDI1ONIBUmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm15bG9uZG9uLm5ld3MvbmV3cy9wcm9wZXJ0eS9pbS1lc3RhdGUtYWdlbnQtcmVudGluZy1zb3V0aC0yNjA2MDI1OC5hbXA?oc=5&ucbcb=1&hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB:en`

This appeared to be working fine prior to updating to d10 that also includes symfony 4-6 update behind the scenes, so not sure if that is related?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this a little more I believe the issue I was having is more to do with Google using Javascript to handle the redirect. I have tested this by turning javascript off in the browser and doing so the redirect does not work. This is in combination with all News links in rss feeds now linking to Google first rather than the final source.

So to overcome this I have had to add an additional step that extracts the url from this middle page which I can then use to do the final lookup.